# How can I send mail with PHP's mail() function and MAMP Pro?

Tags: php, email, mamp

I'm developing a website that will utilize PHP's mail() function. I'm running MAMP Pro (primarily because it has the Postfix feature that is supposed to be useful for sending emails). I feel like I've tried everything, but my program still won't send emails. It doesn't even really matter to me that I use mail(). I just want to be able to send emails from my local MAMP Pro webserver so I can test out my website. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try sending the email to a local address - I believe MAMP can send emails over the local network fine as it uses your systems built-in SMTP.

Comment: More information is required for us to be able to help you. Does sending mails works from commandline? Do you get an error when trying to send mails through PHP. Is your mail correctly setup when you do a `phpinfo()`

Comment: Did you figure it out? If you got it working, then post a solution and accept it as an answer, so others with the same problem will have somewhere to see it. If you still need help, what more can you tell us of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it up for your ISP.

http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/server/postfix

also

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-sending-emails-with-mamp-pro.html

Other than that, I agree with the comments. What is your ISP? What is php telling you? Also, read your logfile for postfix and tell us what it says:

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2010/03/how-to-show-postfix-log-file-of-mamp.html